# Is there anything like orderBySize in QueryOptions Class of Windows.Storage.Search Namespace?

Tags: uwp

I use QueryOptions Class of Windows.Storage.Search Namespace, to query storage files in a folder or library, without issues. My current requirement is to find the duplicate files, but I could find only OrderByDate & OrderByName in the CommonFileQuery Enum, and a few more which not helpful for finding duplicates. Is there any way/workaround to query with orderBySize or checksum? and create a unique list from that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may see the [following list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/properties/core-bumper). As an example, you can try the following code to see if you can query by filesize:

```
 QueryOptions queryOptions = new QueryOptions(CommonFileQuery.DefaultQuery, fileTypeFilter);
        queryOptions.SortOrder.Clear();
        SortEntry sortey= new SortEntry();
        sortey.PropertyName = "System.TotalFileSize";
        sortey.AscendingOrder = false;
        queryOptions.SortOrder.Add(sortey);
```

But you also need to notice the remark [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.search.queryoptions.sortorder):

If the folder being queried is not in a library or in the HomeGroup folder, SortOrder only supports entries based on the System.ItemNameDisplay (PKEY_ItemNameDisplay), System.Search.Rank (PKEY_Search_Rank), or System.DateModified (PKEY_DateModified) properties; SortOrder entries based on any other properties will return E_INVALIDARG.

Comment: Thanks. So apparently there is no way to sort by size in a folder other than Library or HomeGroup! It makes the job difficult, since I have to iterate through loop to find FileSize of every file. It would take long time for the operation to complete.

Comment: @MgBhadurudeen Hmmm. Did you notice the doc on [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/fast-file-properties). Actually "Apps can request the user to add the location to the index using StorageLibrary.RequestAddFolderAsync. Once the location is included, it will be automatically indexed and apps can use this technique to enumerate the files. "

Comment: @MgBhadurudeen This means if your user give your app the permission you can then add the specific folder to libraries. Then you can query the specific properties.